# How to design a pom.xml to cater to disconnected teams for Maven repo behind a firewall?

Tags: maven, repository, maven-3

I have a development team working on Java projects behind a firewall. So we use our own repo for internally developed dependencies. In our POM I have:

```xml
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>ACME</id>
            <!-- behind the firewall -->
            <url>https://mavenrepo.acme.com</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

Works like a charm. Now I'm, getting a second development team at a different location, behind a different firewall. The teams share sources via Git, but are not allowed to access each other's firewall protected maven repositories.

What can I do, short of DNS shenaniganery, to have a single `pom.xml` that pulls dependencies from different repositories depending on availability?

**Followup**

Based on comments below the solution would be like this?

```xml
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>ACME</id>
            <!-- NO URL HERE -->
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

and

```xml
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                              https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>ACME</id>
      <!-- URL here -->
      <url>https://mavenrepo.acme.com</url>
      <username>some user</username>
      <password>encrypted creds</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
</settings>
```

Would that work?

Comment: Start using a repository manager ...and configure that in your settings.xml file instead of in the pom file...

Comment: That is right. Repositories should be configured in the `settings.xml`, not the `pom.xml`

Comment: I have the credentials in the settings.xml. Slightly hesitant to put the URL there since that info should imho be in version control - but I shall give it a shot

Comment: You can also separate out the credentials from the `settings.xml` (https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-encryption.html) and put the `settings.xml` into version control